# Angular - Get data from a service for a form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I want to create a form in Angular, but I need some data for placeholders. This data is retrieved from a service as JSON with three fields.

I don't really understand how TypeScript works so I might be doing a very basic mistake, but here's the code :

```
export class Component{
    public data:{
        id: string,
        quantity: number,
        ref: string
    };

    constructor(private service: Service){
        this.data = this.service.getDataById(id) // I get the id from elsewhere
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    form = new FormGroup({
        id: new FormControl(this.data.id, Validators.required),
        ref: new FormControl(this.data.ref, Validators.required),
        quantity: new FormControl(this.data.quantity, Validators.required),
    })
}
```

Also here is my service:

```
export class service{
    /* @ngInject */
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getDataById(id: number): Observable<{
        id: string;
        quantity: number;
        ref: string;
    }> {
        return this.http.get<{
            id: string;
            quantity: number;
            ref: string;
        }>(`api/getOfById/${id}`);
    }
}
```

I know I get the values because my API returns the JSON response with the three fields:

```
{
  creationTimestamp: /*the time*/, 
  data:{
    id: /*value*/,
    quantity: /*value*/,
    ref: /*value*/
  }
}
```

First I got an error as my service returns an `Observable`, so I modified my `data` to be:

```
public data: Observable<{
    id: string;
    quantity: number;
    ref: string;
  }>;
```

But then I get an error on my `this.data.id`:

> TS2729: Property 'data' is used before its initialization.

I don't understand this error as the data is initialized in my constructor.

What am I missing here? How do I get the data from my JSON to the `data` in my component?

**Update:**

Now I have this:

```
export class Component{
  data: { id: string; quantity: number; ref: string };
  constructor(
    private service: Service
  ) {
    this.service
      .getDataById(id)
      .subscribe((value) => {
        this.data = value;
      });
  }
  //...
}
```

but I still have the same error : `this.data.id`:

> TS2729: Property 'data' is used before its initialization.

**Update 2:**

After Yong Shun's answer, now I have:

```
export class Component {
  data!: { id: string; quantity: number; ref: string };
  constructor(
    private service: Service
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service
      .getDataById(id)
      .subscribe((value) => {
        this.data = value;
      });
  }

  form = new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(this.data.id, Validators.required),
    ref: new FormControl(this.data.ref, Validators.required),
    quantity: new FormControl(this.data.quantity,Validators.required),
  })
}
```

Now I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: As `data` is observable, you have to `subscribe` it. See [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt4).

Comment: use this['data'] for prevent that error.

Comment: In addition, I think it is better to do this in ngOnint. And if you absolutely have to use it in the initialization of the component, use Resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird error message as I don't see any `of` variable from your attached code.

1. Possibly try to add an exclamation mark after the `data` variable.

```
public data!: {
    id: string,
    quantity: number,
    ref: string
};
```

This represents `data` is not null.

2. Don't perform data initialization in `constructor`. Use the Angular [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#lifecycle-hook) such as `ngOnInit` method.
3. `this.service.getDataById(id)` returns an `Observable`. You should grab the data returned from the `Observable` with `.subscribe()`. Also, assign the value for the `form` as well.

```
form!: FormGroup;

constructor(private service: Service) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.service.getDataById(id)
    .subscribe({
      next(data) => {
        this.data = data;

        this.form = new FormGroup({
          id: new FormControl(this.data.id, Validators.required),
          ref: new FormControl(this.data.ref, Validators.required),
          quantity: new FormControl(this.data.quantity, Validators.required),
        });
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and updated the question

Comment: Hi @Neo, I updated my answer. Sorry for missing out. Since you need to assign value to `form` with `this.data`, you should also done the assignation within the `.subscribe` function, which means assign when the Observable is returned.